# how to set background image in html Service of Google app script for Send Email?

Tags: html, jquery, css, google-apps-script

I using Google app script for sending email but I can't set background image before sending email.

I tried jquery  and css for set background image but not working

This mail not show background image
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <base target="_top">
      <!-- CSS only -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <?!= include("style");?>
   </head>
   <style>
      *{
      }
      body {
        background-image: url('cid:https://miyagen8.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/background.png');
  
}
   </style>
  
   <body>
     <div  >
     
      <p> <?= client.company ?> </p>
      <p> <?= client.department ?> </p>
      <p> <?= client.derector ?> </p>
      <p> <?= client.name ?>様 </p>
      <p>いつもお世話になります。</p>
      <p>Text body</p>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: you should check first the image url you added is working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the official document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css), I had thought that `background-image` might be able to be used. So, for example, in your situation, when `background-image` is included in the tag of `body` as the inline style, is that the result you expect?

#### From:

```
<body>
```

#### To:

```
<body style="background-image: url('https://miyagen8.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/background.png')">
```

#### Reference:

- [CSS Support](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this for an [example](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-background-images-in-email/). From what I can tell this is not a valid link: `cid:https://miyagen8.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/background.png` because you are setting two protocolls `cid` and `https`. Therefore remove the `cid:` and it should work with this:
`https://miyagen8.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/background.png`

Comment: I tried your way before but it didn't work. So then I refer to this page [This Page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) add `cid` to my code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have added a photo to the question section above. Hope you help